# Assigning a javascript variable at onclick function

Tags: javascript

OK.In the below code .I am trying to pass parameter images[i] with single quotes so that the onclick can work,however I am not able to do so(paramaeters are not getting passed with single quotes) by applying the below logic.Can anyone pls sussgest what is missing here .

```
  for (i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
document.write("<img onclick='currentimage('+images[1]+')' class='photo'  src='" +  images[i] + "' width='160' height='120'/>");
}
```

Comment: use \" instead if ': onclick='currentimage(\"+images[1]+\")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to end one string literal before you try to concatenate something else on to it.

You also can't nest different quote types without escaping them.

```
document.write("<img onclick='currentimage(&quot;" + images[1] + "&quot;)' class='photo' src='" +  images[i] + "' width='160' height='120'/>");
```

… but do yourself a favour. Don't try to nest JavaScript inside HTML inside JavaScript. It will just give you a headache.

Use DOM instead. Use semantic markup while you are at it.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('someContainer');
for (i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
    parent.appendChild(makeButton(images[i]);
}

function makeButton(image) {
    var button_element = document.createElement("button");
    var image_element = document.createElement("img");
    button_element.appendChild(image_element);
    image_element.src = image;
    image_element.className = "photo";
    image_element.width = 160;
    image_element.height = 120;
    button_element.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        currentimage(image);
    });
    return button_element;
}
```

It's longer, but much easier to see what is going on and to debug.